# How to add unique constraint to column with LongText datatype in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

Can i add unique constraint to LongText column in laravel.
I mean, for example i have table having body column with LongText datatype, then how i can make it unique.

```
  $table->LongText('body')->unique();
```

When i do this it will generate the following SQL error.

```html
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'long_questi
on' used in key specification without a key length (SQL: alter table `long_questions` add unique `long_questions_long_question
_unique`(`long_question`))
```

I need need a solution for this to make a LongText column unique...
please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

According to me. You can't make `text` to `unique`.

`string` can be .

`$table->string('sensitive_string', 255)->unique();`

Comment: string can't accept more data and my requirement is to accept larg amount of data and make it unique... so how can i achieve this????

Comment: @RiazKhan maybe best option would be, validating such rules before attempting storing into database